# Долго загружается сайт на Tomcat 8 Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: tomcat, site

Стоит TomCat 8 на Ubuntu 16.04. Сайт очень долго грузится. файлы не сохраняются в кеше браузера.На локале все норм, а вот на сервере долго все. И почему-то во вкладке Network у файлов статус 304. в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Файлы сохраняются в кеше браузера, но браузер каждый раз спрашивает сервер, `а не изменились ли на сервере файлы, которые я скачал вчера?` (и сервер кодом 304 отвечает `нет, не изменились, можешь использовать файл из кеша`). Если это статические файлы, то к ним можно добавить заголовок `cache-control: immutable`

Comment: @diraria ну хорошо. ладно с этим. но почему грузится долго. переустановил всю систему, вместе с ОС и все равно.

Comment: надо больше деталей, например скриншот вкладки network не помешает. а вообще причин, как мне кажется, может быть очень много

Comment: @diraria скорее всего это тормозил хостинг.